# How to force a specific process to use a proxy for network communication

Tags: windows, process, proxy, http-proxy

There are a few programs like [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/) that can force an exe to use a proxy. There are a few others, too. But the sites all look a bit shady. I don't even trust Proxifier tbh... So I'd like to know how these programs work. How do they do it? Is there a WinAPI function that can be used to do that? Or do you have to actually inject code into the processes?

I was only able to find functions to change the global proxy of windows. But some programs don't care what the global proxy says, they always try to connect directly, even if it's not possible...

Comment: I *think* you would use an NDIS filter driver for this sort of thing.  But I'm not familiar with the technology.

Comment: I know that wireshark uses some technology that works on the driver level. It is able to capture all network traffic on my PC, but it's too low-level to know which process has sent which packet. So I think that what you suggested won't work.

Comment: Why would you need to know which process had sent a packet?  (But I suspect that you can, if you need to; wouldn't the packet's source port uniquely identify the process it came from?)

Comment: It's important because how else would I force a single processes traffic though a proxy? I mean I didn't ask for a way to make the whole system use a proxy. I really like the process identification by port idea, I haven't thought about that before.

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  In my environment I would usually want to force everything to use the proxy.  Perhaps there's some open source you could look at?  Anything that implements a firewall or redirects or manipulates traffic could give you a clue.  (I'm afraid you're not likely to get a definitive answer here any time soon; I don't think any of the regulars are experts in this field.)

Comment: This is a tough one.

Here's an idea:

Host a transparent proxy that consumes the original proxy. Then point the machines at the new transparent proxy machines as the default gateway. See [link](http://markus.revti.com/2009/01/squid-transparent-proxy-server-on-windows-server-2003/) here.

Comment: What do you mean by "original proxy"? What if the application doesn't use a proxy?

Comment: Sorry I'm not explaining all that well. So here is goes.

You have applications running on machine A. You want them to use the proxy on machine B. 

There's something called a transparent proxy. Basically applications will use it without knowing. You can just set the default gateway on the machines and all applications will be using the transparent proxy.

My suggestion is to setup a transparent proxy on machine C or a VM that itself uses the proxy on machine B. You then set the default gateway on machine A to be the ip address of machine C.

Comment: If you are uncomforable with two proxies (could have all sorts of problems), check out [link](https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn) BadVPN. It seems to have the same functionality as proxifier but this is open source and on github.

Comment: @Just1689, that BadVPN link is interesting. I see the Tun2socks part of it is supposed to work on Windows too, so that's cool.

Answer (score 6):

Proxifier is based on [LSP (layered service provider)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider), but personally I never liked this technology because of often stability issues. However, besides LSP there are other possible approaches suitable to achieve the same functionality, you can find a short coverage of network filtering methods (including LSP) here: https://www.ntkernel.com/ndis-hooking-drivers-and-legacy-windows-systems/, however the document is a little bit out-of-date, I have written it in times of early Windows XP dawn and it does not cover WFP (Windows Filtering Platform), which replaced TDI, and NDIS Lightweight Filter, which replaced NDIS Intermediate and NDIS-hooking drivers. Both technologies were introduced by Windows Vista along with NDIS 6.0.

Comment: Proxifier worked great. Thanks! It was just the thing I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think Wininet.dll is the canonical method for accessing HTTP from user mode programs on Windows. (The documentation for Windows Networking and Internet support is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663286(v=vs.85).aspx). I didn't want to go through all of the doc, but I'm pretty sure Wininet.dll is the right one)

One method for doing a per process proxy, is to write a DLL that acts like Wininet.dll (and sits on top of the Windows' Wininet.dll). Your Wininet would have some sort of mechanism (registry, config file, etc.) to determine whether a particular process is to be proxied or not. If process isn't proxied then all calls go through to original Wininet, but if process is proxied then your Wininet does the redirection.

Another, somewhat similar, injection point is at the winsock layer (ws2_32.dll). (Back in the Windows 3.1, Win95 era, it was fairly common to replace winsock.dll (ws2_32 predecessor) by vendors of TCP/IP stacks.) [Here's](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-01&post=Proxocket---A-Winsock-Proxy-Sniffer) a case where the same concept is used to capture traffic at winsock layer. The article at the link has a nice diagram that illustrates the concept as well as implementation details of replacing ws2_32.dll.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to do this is to use Windows Filtering Platform.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Filtering_Platform

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page

> Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) is a set of API and system services
>   that provide a platform for creating network filtering applications.
>   The WFP API allows developers to write code that interacts with the
>   packet processing that takes place at several layers in the networking
>   stack of the operating system. **Network data can be filtered and also
>   modified before it reaches its destination.**